# Angular Service Worker - Old build still serving - need an Angular solution

Tags: angular, service-worker

Edit to an Edit:

See the answer below. Angular SW was actually functioning/hashing, etc just fine. The problem was the server was *re-hashing* certain bundles, causing a mismatch, and therefore the SW would constantly show a mismatch between the client and the server.

Edit:

Maybe I need to be clearer. I referenced a question and linked to it, and seem to be getting downvoted because of it, yet with no comments given. The accepted answer to that question did not solve my issue, and was a pure javascript based approach. I need help coming up with an ANGULAR way to solve the following problem:

> After a page refresh, the service worker shows a new build. After Chrome is closed and the app is reopened, the old build shows instead of the new build.

As noted below, I implemented the accepted answer to the referenced question and it did not solve the issue.

Original Post:

Look, I have problem that others have come across before with version control via a Service Worker. As best noted in the following question:

[Angular Service Worker intermittently serving old version of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546347/angular-service-worker-intermittently-serving-old-version-of-application)

I have the exact same problem - initial client refresh serves the new build, leaving the window and coming back to it shows the old build. Another refresh and another leave and come back seems to then make the new build persist. This is immensely confusing.

The provided solution to above answer, however, seems to indicate that we should make a separate .js file to control the update/removal/registration behavior of our service worker. I have a problem with that approach seeing as the whole point of Angular and our ngsw-config file is to control the service worker from that file alone.

My question is simple: Is there an Angular approach to unregister all service workers, then reload the URL once we're done?

Based on this article: https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/

I created and tried to use the following code:

```
   window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then( (registrations) => {
      
      for (let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister().then(() => {

          //The problem line
          return window.navigator.serviceWorker.clients.matchAll();

        }).then((clients) => {
          clients.forEach(client => {
            if (client.url && "navigate" in client) {
              client.navigate(client.url);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
```

Where my window service is the following:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { ClassProvider, FactoryProvider, InjectionToken, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

/* Create a new injection token for injecting the window into a component. */
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('WindowToken');

/* Define abstract class for obtaining reference to the global window object. */
export abstract class WindowRef {

  get nativeWindow(): Window | Object {
    throw new Error('Not implemented.');
  }

}

/* Define class that implements the abstract class and returns the native window object. */
export class BrowserWindowRef extends WindowRef {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  get nativeWindow(): Window | Object {
    return window;
  }

}

/* Create an factory function that returns the native window object. */
export function windowFactory(browserWindowRef: BrowserWindowRef, platformId: Object): Window | Object {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
    return browserWindowRef.nativeWindow;
  }
  return new Object();
}

/* Create a injectable provider for the WindowRef token that uses the BrowserWindowRef class. */
export const browserWindowProvider: ClassProvider = {
  provide: WindowRef,
  useClass: BrowserWindowRef
};

/* Create an injectable provider that uses the windowFactory function for returning the native window object. */
export const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: windowFactory,
  deps: [ WindowRef, PLATFORM_ID ]
};

/* Create an array of providers. */
export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [
  browserWindowProvider,
  windowProvider
];
```

So I can access the window as an injectable.

The problem is that I cannot access the [clients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients) property of the service worker - it seems that it is only accessible in a service worker file itself.

So now my approach is the following (which uses sort of what Angular recommends on their docs, part of the above approach, and my own code). Please ignore the debuggers.

```
    const appIsStable$ = appRef.isStable.pipe(takeWhile(isStable => isStable === true));
    const everyMinute$ = interval(60*1000);
    const swUpdateCheck$ = concat(appIsStable$, everyMinute$);

    swUpdateCheck$.subscribe(() => {
      debugger;
      swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
        debugger;
        console.log('new version available');
        if(!this.dialog.getDialogById('new-version')) {
          this._dialog.openDialog('new-version', 'new-version');
          this._dual.nVDialogData$.subscribe((res) => {
            if(res){
              //this.window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then( (registrations) => {
                debugger;
                // for (let registration of registrations) {
                //   debugger;
                //   registration.unregister();
                //   // unregister() every old registration here...
                //   // force page reload here necessary?...
                // }
                this.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => {
                  this.window.location.reload();
                  //Is this what will trigger a new controller?
                });
              //});
            }
          });
        }
      }, (rej) => {
        debugger;
      });
    });
```

And this works... I actually get my alert dialog like so:

[image: alert dialog]

The problem is, that if I hit 'Get new build' - which just reloads my location - One minute later, I get the same window showing up...

In the developer console, I can see that I'm still running the same service worker. So refreshing the app didn't actually get me a new worker.

If I uncomment out some code like so (registration loop taken from accepted answer to referenced question above), I successfully unregister the old worker and register a new worker, but still 1 minute later, I keep getting this pop up about a new build, even though I have a brand new worker and my app shows that I am on the new build.

```
swUpdateCheck$.subscribe(() => {
      debugger;
      swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
        debugger;
        console.log('new version available');
        if(!this.dialog.getDialogById('new-version')) {
          this._dialog.openDialog('new-version', 'new-version');
          this._dual.nVDialogData$.subscribe((res) => {
            if(res){
              this.window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then( (registrations) => {
                debugger;
                for (let registration of registrations) {
                  debugger;
                  registration.unregister();
                  // unregister() every old registration here...
                  // force page reload here necessary?...
                }
                this.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => {
                  this.window.location.reload();
                  //Is this what will trigger a new controller?
                });
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }, (rej) => {
        debugger;
      });
    });
```

What is going on here? Why isn't the update actually applying in either scenario?

The only thing that makes an update apply correctly is clearing application data then empty cache and hard reload.

What am I doing wrong? To my knowledge the new build should persist correctly after it is shown post refresh. Am I wrong about assuming that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See answer below, but this question is resolved. There wasn't actually anything wrong with how/why the service worker was updating. What was wrong was Google's Roboto font getting a new hash every single time the page was revisited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lied with our server. Here is a brief synopsis that I hope will help you.

- At the time, we were using a very rudimentary deployment approach using a pull from bitbucket.
- Because our server was referencing a .git repository, it was providing it's own hash values to our files
- This is what was causing the "service worker error" at the time. Bad hashing!

The end short-term fix ended up being to tell git (on our server) to not re-hash files at all. This kept our bundles/cached fonts, etc with the same hash that was made at build time in Angular.

The other thing that was immensely helpful was using the `/ngsw/state` visual tool that the service worker provides.

If you are unfamiliar with that, simply type in your root URL (localhost:4200/ or [www.yoursite.com](http://www.yoursite.com)) then type in /ngsw/state

That will help you exactly know what the problem is. Our hash mismatch became readily identifiable as a result.

The long term fix would be to use a pipeline or better deployment mechanism. We were contsrained to git for a while and had to work with it.

I hope this helps someone.